# PHP Merge 2 Arrays & SORT_ASC

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge, ksort

I would like to merge (combine) 2 arrays and sort them in ascending order. The data comes from the database and is actually already sorted in ascending order but when I merge them, the data for the second array only appears after the e.g. last Z word in the first array. My intention is as per example below is to sort the merged array by [companyname].

Any idea what I could be missing below?

Both array formats:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array([id] => 1 [companyname] => 180 Degrees [region] => western_cape)
    [1] => Array([id] => 2 [companyname] => 4 Ever Sheeting [region] => gauteng)
    [2] => Array([id] => 3 [companyname] => A I Sheeting [region] => gauteng)
)
```

Merge like so:

```
$arr = array_merge( $arr1, $arr2 );
```

SORT_ASC like so:

```
ksort( $arr, SORT_ASC );
```

Results: 
The items from $arr2 only start after ALL $arr1 items.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: They will, because array_merge() __appends__ the entries from $arr2 to $arr1, modifying their numeric keys accordingly, and then you're sorting by the array key

Comment: Do you mean that you want to sort by the `id` element of each array?

Comment: And can't simply use a single database query with a UNION and an ORDER BY to retrieve this data already merged and sorted?

Comment: @MarkBaker In other words it's not possible to do this as I'm attempting? I've to resort into a MySQL query as you suggested? And I would like to SORT by Company Name (string) and not Ids

Comment: No, it's perfectly possible to sort by company name.... I just needed to clarify what you wanted

Comment: Though handling this at the database level is more efficient if you can do that instead

Comment: To do what you want in PHP: rather than using `ksort($arr, SORT_ASC);`, use `usort($arr, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['company_name'], $b['company_name']); });`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the above, it works perfectly...!